# Automated program install (and launch) on Surface pro from Linux

Tags: linux, windows-10, remote-access, microsoft-surface

I'm currently facing with a task on remotely deploying an UWP (Universal Windows Platform) application on Microsoft Surface pro tablets. 
In short I'm developing a robot which communicates with surface using local area network via USB-Ethernet dongle and physical interaction programmable robotic arm which can have Surface pen attached to it.
The task is to make a system in which a user inserts Factory-resetted Surface into robot and connects USB-Ethernet dongle to it, the robot could be able to automatically install custom-made UWP app into surface, launch it and interact with this app using Ethernet cable and robotic arm.

Current main problem is how to connect to factory resetted Surface and launch any application on it remotely from Linux? Basically if I already have connection to Surface's command prompt or Powershell, that can count as mission accomplished, because from there I can just launch download (from linux machine), launch and install scripts and done.

On the linux machine I can install various applications which might be useful in this case.  I have seen many solutions which require 3<sup>rd</sup> party programs installed, but these Surfaces only have Win 10 (build 15063).

Powershell via OpenSSH is viable, but this build doesn't have openssh built into yet.

Comment: Why don't you use the robotic arm to setup the surface to a state where you can connect to it from the Linux machine?

Comment: Yes, this is also a good option, but how do i know windows spawn on surface's desktop are always on the same place so i could rely clicking on that place, also just by setting up IPv4 address by robotic arm takes more than 33 highly coordinated clicks.
Is there an option to automate these processes ?
and also what kind of configuration should be done on surface so I could connect it to the Linux machine ?
and what can I configure on a surface in the first place ? what software Surface had built in which Linux could connect to and give commands to setup Surface further ?

Comment: TBH, I hope that taking over a factory reset Surface via Ethernet is impossible. Another option is PXE boot, but I don't know if your robot is capable of doing that. According to Microsoft, you'll need a keyboard connected to the surface. If you find a reliable way to open powershell, you can then use the on screen keyboard which should always be at the same position. From there you can download and a script from your Linux machine and execute it. If you are allowed to connect one additional USB device you can use a rubberducky or HID capable arduino to emulate key presses and set things up.